# ddwrt + Freeradius + LDAP

Tags: openldap, freeradius

I am trying to set up an LDAP server for authenticating multiple servers such as ftp and radius (maybe even ssh?)

I have a router (ddwrt) which I have been able to authenticate with plaintext passwords in freeradius. Now I want to use an ldap server to store the users and passwords

I have set up my ldap server and I can authenticate it using the following:

```
kevin@kevin-desktop:~$ radtest ldapuser password123 127.0.0.1 2 testing123
Sending Access-Request of id 182 to 127.0.0.1 port 1812
        User-Name = "ldapuser"
        User-Password = "password123"
        NAS-IP-Address = 127.0.1.1
        NAS-Port = 2
        Message-Authenticator = 0x00000000000000000000000000000000
rad_recv: Access-Accept packet from host 127.0.0.1 port 1812, id=182, length=20
```

But when I try to authenticate using ddwrt -> freeradius I get the following message:

```
rad_recv: Access-Request packet from host 192.168.11.1 port 52101, id=0, length=129
        User-Name = "ldapuser"
        NAS-IP-Address = 192.168.11.1
        Called-Station-Id = "10da43747fcb"
        Calling-Station-Id = "accf8528974e"
        NAS-Identifier = "10da43747fcb"
        NAS-Port = 49
        Framed-MTU = 1400
        NAS-Port-Type = Wireless-802.11
        EAP-Message = 0x0200000d016c64617075736572
        Message-Authenticator = 0x99372f408b0979fc103af5112b81501a
# Executing section authorize from file /etc/freeradius/sites-enabled/default
+group authorize {
++[preprocess] = ok
++[chap] = noop
++[mschap] = noop
++[digest] = noop
[suffix] No '@' in User-Name = "ldapuser", looking up realm NULL
[suffix] No such realm "NULL"
++[suffix] = noop
[eap] EAP packet type response id 0 length 13
[eap] No EAP Start, assuming it's an on-going EAP conversation
++[eap] = updated
[files] users: Matched entry DEFAULT at line 1
++[files] = ok
[ldap] performing user authorization for ldapuser
[ldap]  expand: %{Stripped-User-Name} -> 
[ldap]  ... expanding second conditional
[ldap]  expand: %{User-Name} -> ldapuser
[ldap]  expand: (uid=%{%{Stripped-User-Name}:-%{User-Name}}) -> (uid=ldapuser)
[ldap]  expand: dc=kevin,dc=local -> dc=kevin,dc=local
  [ldap] ldap_get_conn: Checking Id: 0
  [ldap] ldap_get_conn: Got Id: 0
  [ldap] attempting LDAP reconnection
  [ldap] (re)connect to 192.168.11.21:389, authentication 0
  [ldap] bind as cn=admin,dc=kevin,dc=local/pwd to 192.168.11.21:389
  [ldap] waiting for bind result ...
  [ldap] Bind was successful
  [ldap] performing search in dc=kevin,dc=local, with filter (uid=ldapuser)
[ldap] No default NMAS login sequence
[ldap] looking for check items in directory...
  [ldap] userPassword -> User-Password == "{SSHA}fqS7t/ZXimCnTgsXcsGDQF9WP+atmjVG"
  [ldap] userPassword -> Password-With-Header == "{SSHA}fqS7t/ZXimCnTgsXcsGDQF9WP+atmjVG"
[ldap] looking for reply items in directory...
  [ldap] ldap_release_conn: Release Id: 0
++[ldap] = ok
++[expiration] = noop
++[logintime] = noop
[pap] WARNING: Auth-Type already set.  Not setting to PAP
++[pap] = noop
+} # group authorize = updated
Found Auth-Type = LDAP
# Executing group from file /etc/freeradius/sites-enabled/default
+group LDAP {
  [ldap] Attribute "User-Password" is required for authentication.
  You seem to have set "Auth-Type := LDAP" somewhere.
  THAT CONFIGURATION IS WRONG.  DELETE IT.
  YOU ARE PREVENTING THE SERVER FROM WORKING PROPERLY.
++[ldap] = invalid
+} # group LDAP = invalid
Failed to authenticate the user.
Using Post-Auth-Type Reject
# Executing group from file /etc/freeradius/sites-enabled/default
+group REJECT {
[eap] Request was previously rejected, inserting EAP-Failure
++[eap] = updated
[attr_filter.access_reject]     expand: %{User-Name} -> ldapuser
attr_filter: Matched entry DEFAULT at line 11
++[attr_filter.access_reject] = updated
+} # group REJECT = updated
Delaying reject of request 0 for 1 seconds
Going to the next request
Waking up in 0.9 seconds.
Sending delayed reject for request 0
Sending Access-Reject of id 0 to 192.168.11.1 port 52101
        EAP-Message = 0x04000004
        Message-Authenticator = 0x00000000000000000000000000000000
Waking up in 4.9 seconds.
Cleaning up request 0 ID 0 with timestamp +9
Ready to process requests.
```

How do I properly set up openradius with openldap?

Comment: specify your realm or use pam and sssd (which I found way easier)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently You have to store the passwords in cleartext on the ldap server for PEAP to work.

I followed this tutorial (Very basic setup):
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=weTfRslHhZY

**Steps:**

**In /etc/freeradius/modules/ldap**
modify the settings:

```
server = "server.address"
        identity = "cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com"
        password = admin_password
        basedn = "dc=example,dc=com"
```

**In /etc/freeradius/sites-available/default**
authorize section:

```
comment file
uncomment ldap
```

**In /etc/freeradius/sites-available/inner-tunnel**

authorize section:

```
comment file
uncomment ldap
```

authenticate section:
uncomment:

```
Auth-Type LDAP {
        ldap
}
```

They omitted the fact that you have to keep the passwords in clear text which I found out about here:

http://tech.sybreon.com/2011/01/18/freeradius-openldap-dd-wrt/

Apparently you cant create a posix account from a simple organizational group, you have to create it from a posix group which I got from here:

http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-networking-3/can't-create-ldap-entries-with-phpldapadmin-272376/

In the end I had to use jxexplore and phpldapadmin to add my users since jxexplore does not like to add plaintext passwords. Just create the account without a password on jxexplore then add the password to the user in phpldapadmin. (I will update this when I get the chance)

Answer (score 0):

The key message here is:

> [ldap] Attribute "User-Password" is required for authentication.
>   You seem to have set "Auth-Type := LDAP" somewhere.   THAT
>   CONFIGURATION IS WRONG.  DELETE IT.   YOU ARE PREVENTING THE SERVER
>   FROM WORKING PROPERLY.

I can't see an update section, but I bet that you've either set [set_auth_type](https://github.com/FreeRADIUS/freeradius-server/blob/v2.x.x/raddb/modules/ldap#L170) to yes, or that entry at line 1 of `raddb/users` has something like:

```
DEFAULT Auth-Type := LDAP
```

For either case, you should remove the entry.

By setting Auth-Type you are forcing the server to perform a particular type of authentication which might not be suitable given the attributes in the request.

A description of how the server decides which authentication method to use is available at the [RADIUS Concepts](http://wiki.freeradius.org/guide/Concepts) on the [FreeRADIUS wiki](http://wiki.freeradius.org).

For EAP authentication (which is what DD-WRT is attempting), you need to add the LDAP and PAP modules to the authorize section of `sites-available/inner-tunnel`, and ensure your [Password-With-Header](https://github.com/FreeRADIUS/freeradius-server/blob/v2.x.x/raddb/ldap.attrmap#L41) attribute points to the correct LDAP attribute.